# What`s wrong with my output?

Tags: javascript, output

I'm trying to do a guessing number game, and it's right output should display line by line : Attempt 1 Your guess xx is too small(big)
               Attempt 2 Your guess xx is too small(big)
               Attempt 2 Your guess xx is too small(big)
                  ...

but my output is always changing at the same line like this:
Attempt 3 Your guess xx is too small(big) 
 I don't know the problem,please help.

```
<html>
<head> <title> Guessing game </title>
</head>
<body onload="noGen()" >
<script type = "text/javascript">
var theNumber;
function noGen(){ 
theNumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*999+0) ; //get a random number 
}
</script>
<h1> Guessing game </h1>
<p> You have 10 chances! </p>
<p>Hint: the number is between 0 and 999 </p>

<p id="myguess"> </p>
<p>
<input id="tryno" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="GUESS" onclick="attempt()" />
</p>
<script type= "text/javascript">
i=0;
function attempt(){ 
var guess=document.getElementById('tryno');
var myNumber=guess.value;
i++;
if(i<11)
     { 
if (myNumber<theNumber){
       document.getElementById("myguess").innerHTML="Attempt  "+i+" Your    guess "+ myNumber+ " is too small";

}
else if (myNumber>theNumber) 
   {document.getElementById("myguess").innerHTML="Attempt "+i+"  Your guess "+ myNumber+ " is too big";
```

}

```
else if (myNumber==theNumber){ 
document.getElementById("myguess").innerHTML="Attempt "+i+"  Your guess "+ myNumber+ " is correct"; 
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML= "You win!";}  }
else
  {  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML= "You lose!";}
```

}

```
</script>
<p id="info"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont see anything immediately wrong.
I suggest you write a function `outputResults(guess, i){}` to handle writing the messages. Then you can also do `console.log(i, guess, theNumber)` inside that function and more easily diagnose the problem with the F12 console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to keep the previous results and keep adding to them in a list try this:

```
if (myNumber<theNumber){
            var parSmall = document.createElement("P");
            var ansSmall = document.createTextNode("\nAttempt  "+i+" Your    guess "+ myNumber+ " is too small");
            parSmall.appendChild(ansSmall);
            document.getElementById("myguess").appendChild(parSmall);


        }
        else if (myNumber>theNumber) {
            var par = document.createElement("P");
            var ans = document.createTextNode("\nAttempt "+i+"  Your guess "+ myNumber+ " is too big");
            par.appendChild(ans);
            document.getElementById("myguess").appendChild(par);
```

Edit: innerHTML changes the contents of the div, whereas this adds new

elements and the new text to the div so you should get:

```
<p> guess one
<p> guess two
<p> guess three
```

etc.